# Cross-compiling OpenCV with CMake for Pandaboard Ubuntu

Tags: opencv, cmake, pandaboard

I've written (on Ubuntu host) a simple OpenCV Application (opening the videostream from Logitech Webcam Pro 9000) in Qt Creator. After fixing problems (CMake didn't find it) with ffmepeg, x264, gstreamer etc. (found on http://www.ozbotz.org/opencv-installation/) the application works.

Now I want to cross-compile OpenCV with CMake for Pandaboard (Ubuntu), to use it in combination with the cross-compiled Qt Application (like on host). 
After pressing the configure button I get this output.
http://depositfiles.com/files/se4r3bhrh

Besides the problem, I don't know exactly how to write the "toolchain file for cross-compiling" and/or to "Specify Options for cross-compiling" in CMake, I'm afraid to fix the problems with ffmpeg etc. (like on the host)?
I have a good HOWTO (from ozbotz) for host, but how to handle it for cross-compiling for Pandaboard ?

Does anyone has experience/ideas with these problems ?

Answer (score 0):

To cross compile Opencv for pandaboard with a host ubuntu pc,Follow these steps:

- Install cross compiling tools
  On ubuntu, you can simply do it by entering the following in the terminal:

  `sudo apt-get install gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf`

  - Get opencv source and prepare to build

    `mkdir opencv

    cd opencv

    git clone https://github.com/Itseez/opencv.git

    cd opencv-master

    mkdir build

    cd build`
  - Edit Cmake variables to tell it to use the cross compiler.
    `gedit ../platforms/linux/arm-gnueabi.toolchain.cmake`
    add these lines at appropriate place in the file:
    `set( CMAKE_C_COMPILER gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf)

    set( CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER g++-arm-linux-gnueabihf)`
    Set additional C_FLAGS if you need:
    `set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-mcpu=cortex-a8 -O3 -mfloat-abi=hard -ftree-vectorize -ftree-vectorizer-verbose=9" CACHE STRING "c flags")`
  - Run cmake:
    `cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../platforms/linux/arm-gnueabi.toolchain.cmake ../`
  - `make`

Comment: The binary installed by gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf seems to have had a name change to arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc. Similarly, the g++ binary now seems to be arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++.

Comment: To get the g++ compiler, I also needed apt-get install g++-arm-linux-gnueabihf. Use the 'which arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc' and 'which arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++' to find the binaries and confirm they're installed correctly. Not sure why the cmake script wants both gcc and g++, but I needed to install both to get the default cmake script to work.

Comment: We wound up using apt-get python-opencv, which had binaries for arm (pandaboard) already built.